# Match string that doesn't have number after letter

Tags: php, regex, string

I've got a scenario as follows. Our systems needs to pull filters from a string passed in as a query parameter, but also throw a 404 error if the string isn't correctly formatted. So let's take the following three strings as an exmple:

1. pf0pt1000r
2. pfasdfadf
3. pf2000pt2100

By the application requirements, only #3 is supposed to match as a "valid" string. So my current regex to match that is `/([a-z]+)(\d+)/`. But this also matches #1, if not entirely, but it still matches.

My problem thus is twofold - I need 2 patterns, 1 that will match *only* the 3rd string in this list, and another that will match the "not-acceptable" strings 1 and 2. I believe there must be some way to "negate" a pattern (so then I'd technically only need one pattern, I'm assuming), but I'm not sure how exactly to do that.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

For clarity's sake, let me explain. The "filter parameters" present here take the following structure - 1 or 2 letters, followed by a number of, well, numbers. That structure can repeat itself however many times. So for example, valid filter strings could be

- pf100pt2000
- pf100pt2000r2wp0to1
- etc.

Invalid strings could be

- pf10000pt2000r
- pf3000pt2123wpno
- ... anything not following the structure above.

Comment: I don't really see any difference between #1 and #3, except that #3 doesn't end with a letter...

Comment: "DOESN"T have number after letter"? Only #2 would match, then because #1 has `pf0` and `pt1`. do you mean only at the END of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for valid input:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\d+)+$
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/jK6xS3/1)

To find invalid inputs use:

```
^(?!([a-zA-Z]+\d+)+$).+$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/jK6xS3/2)

Answer (score 4):

After clarifying the question:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d+)*$
```

Explanation:

1. `[a-zA-Z]` - a lower or upper case letter
2. `{1,2}` - one or two of those
3. `\d+` - one or more digits
4. `()*` - the whole thing repeated any number of times
5. `^$` - match the entire string from *start*(`^`) to *end*(`$`)

Comment: it could also be just one letter. change `\w{2}`to `\w{1,2}`

Comment: `\w` is alphanumeric, therefore including numbers. Use `[a-zA-Z]` instead.

Comment: @Felk, also fixed. Thank you too!

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(?:(?:[a-z]+)(?:\d+))*$/
```

You were hella close, man.  Just need to repeat that pattern over and over again till the end.

Change the `*` to a `+` to reject the empty string.

Oh, you had more specific requirements, try this:

```
/^(?:[a-z]{1,2}\d+)*$/
```

Broken down:

```
^       - Matches the start of the string an anchor
(?:     - start a non-capturing group
  [a-z] - A to Z.  This you already had.
  {1,2} - Repeat 1 or 2 times
  \d+   - a digit or more You had this, too.
)*      - Repeat that group ad nauseum
$       - Match the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want digits at the end of the string, then

```
/\d$/
```

would do. `\d` = digit, `$` = end of string.